# How to get a label bold in open layers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm labelling markers in a vector layer.

TextOptions of a ol.style.Text object include arrording to the docs (http://ol3js.org/en/v3.0.0-beta.1/apidoc/ol.style.html#TextOptions) no option to change font-weight.

In ol2 I used:

```
fontWeight: "bold"
```

This doesn't seem to work in ol3.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 15):

I found a solution by looking at the example here: https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-labels.html:

```
font = weight + ' ' + size + ' ' + font
```

for instance:

```
font: 'bold 11px Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif'
```

I don't think there is an explanation in the official docs yet - it only says:

- Type: string
- Description: Font

Comment: The docs are always behind the source code/examples in OpenLayers, which I think is reasonable, given how good the examples and how readable the source.

Comment: Useful answer. Of course the examples are good, but it can take times to find exactly what you want !